Remove collar and merge single-layer TIFF files with elliptical projection
I am trying to merge multiple VFR Raster charts into a single one, but unfortunately, the charts are not layered and there is no way to turn off their collars using GDAL.
I am working with GeoTIFF files that represent charts with elliptical map areas. The charts include "collars" (margins around the map) that I need to remove. My goal is to automate the process of cropping the map area and merging multiple GeoTIFF files into a single file. This process needs to be repeatable, as these files are periodically updated.
I've tried using Python libraries like rasterio to detect the map area, but I haven't been able to accurately identify and crop the elliptical map region. The nodata value is undefined in these files, and the background area is not always uniform, which makes it challenging to distinguish the map from the collar.
Is there any tool, library, or approach that can reliably detect the map area and remove the collar? Ideally, it would integrate into a Python workflow, but I'm open to other solutions.
This is the source of the TIFF files I need to modify:
https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/vfr/



Have you looked into gdal's nearblack?  https://gdal.org/en/stable/programs/nearblack.html#cmdoption-nearblack-alg
